# request.getRemoteAddr() returns 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, ip

I am trying the following code to get my ip address in a jsp page:

```
<%
        out.println("Your IP address is " + request.getRemoteAddr());
%>
```

This prints 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, not my ip address. Is this what is suposed to be? Why is not it showing my ip address?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to your servlet container startup script

Comment: Better answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964297/using-request-getremoteaddr-returns-00000001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's your IP address, but not a IPv4 (xx.xx.xx.xx) but a IPv6 one (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx)

EDIT: if your system is mapping IPv4 from/to IPv6 you can infer the algorithm to change between them by reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipv6)

Comment: @bigO [wikipedia's article for IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipv6) mentions a mapping convention between IPv6 and IPv4 and how to do it

Answer (score -2):

JSP code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Hello World</title></head>
<body>
    Hello World!<br/>
    <%
        out.println("Your Host IP address is " + request.getRemoteHost()+"</br>");
        out.println("Your Addr address is " + request.getRemoteAddr()+"</br>");
        out.println("Your Port Post address is " + request.getRemotePort()+"</br>");
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Use http://**127.0.0.1**:8081/hello.jsp gets the result:

```
Hello World!
Your Host IP address is 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
Your Addr address is 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
Your Port Post address is 32432
```

Use http://**localhost**:8081/hello.jsp gets the result:

```
Hello World!
Your Host IP address is 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
Your Addr address is 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
Your Port Post address is 32432
```

Comment: The results you provided are completely identical for both requests. Is that what you meant to say, that there is no difference?

Comment: Yes, there is no difference after my careful observation...LOL

Comment: Yeh, this is um... an interesting answer... to a question I can't imagine