# Using request.getRemoteAddr() returns 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to print the IP address of the logged-in user in my web application. If a user connects from another PC (within the same network, as the web application is running in my pc) using the IP address `192.168.10.120:8080/WebApplication` the code `request.getRemoteAddr()` or `request.getLocalAddr())` returns their IP address. However, when I log in from my pc, which runs the web application, I get this IP address `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`.

Why is this happening? And what's the difference between these commands (which one should I use)? Thank you in advance!

Comment: localhost would return that IP. On other computers you will see actual IP.

Comment: Thanks @Makky do you know the difference between those 2 commands?

Comment: `getLocalAddr()` gets the IP address of the machine to receive the request. [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalAddr()). In contrast, `getRemoteAddr()` obtains the IP address of the machine to request the resource [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr()).

Comment: instead of giving url as "http://localhost:port/" provide url as "http://IP:port/"
You will get remote address.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and there are already accepted answers.

Comment: surprisingly enough, this helped

Comment: This helped too for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In your case, as you are trying to access it on your local machine,so it will return that value. But let one of your friend access it, and you will receive the expected result with `getRemoteAddr`

From the javadoc:

[getRemoteAddr](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29) - Returns the IP address of the client or last proxy that sent the request

[getLocalAddr](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalAddr%28%29) - Returns the IP address of the interface on which the request was received.

Answer (score 68):

As we move over to IPv6 from IPv4, they are changing the loopback address (localhost) to `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` from `127.0.0.1` thats why you are getting this address.

As for the functions:

- `getRemoteAddr()` returns the clients IP
- `getLocalAddr()` returns the IP of the server the application is
  running on

Answer (score 9):

[**getRemoteAddr()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29) solves your purpose but if client is behind any proxy then you will get IP address of proxy :

> Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client or last proxy
>   that sent the request.

**[getLocalAddr](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalAddr%28%29)()** returns the IP of the server the application is running on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get 127.0.0.1 instead of 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 start your application server process with the following property CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

Answer (score 0):

If using java and you need to know the client IP address or the IP address of the localmachine if the application is running on localhost:

```
String ip = "unknown"; 
try{
    ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    if(ip.equals("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1") || ip.equals("127.0.0.1")) {
        InetAddress hostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        ip = hostAddress.getHostAddress();
    }
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    log.info("got unknown host");
    ip = "unknown";
}
```