# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header not found after CORS filter added

Tags: spring-boot, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, cors

I implemented a login form with AngularJS for user authentication. Below is my service for login with post request:

```
app.factory("loginFactory", function ($http) {
    return{
        login: function(username, password) {
            var data = "username="+username+"&password="+password+"&submit=Login";
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/login',
                data: data,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                }
            });  
        }
    }   
});
```

Got the following error when I run it.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/login.No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8081' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I did some research and found out the header has to be added on server side. According this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319396/cors-with-spring-boot-and-angularjs-not-working), I added the following to my Rest Service

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

However, I still got the same error.

Comment: Did you check what `request.getHeader("Origin")` is returning?

Comment: how did you write the get request?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee The login service is actually a post request. See my edits in original post. Since the authentication is handled by spring security, no controller from server side is necessary for `http://localhost:8080/login`.

Comment: Instead of adding the request.getHeader("Origin") try and use this: `request.getRemoteHost()`. If that does not work use this `"request.getHeader() + ":" + request.getRemotePort()"`. That should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the browser looks for `http://127.0.0.1:8081` in the Allow Origin Header, you need to make sure this is getting added in the following line:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:8081");
```

To get the `http://127.0.0.1:8081` you can use :

```
request.getRemoteAddr() + ":" + request.getRemotePort();
```

But if the browser looks for localhost then go for the :

```
request.getRemoteHost().
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Tried all you suggested, still the same. Even tried `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` still does not work

Comment: With Post the problem is , it first sends a preflight request, which gets blocked by the browser.

Comment: You can try disabling the web-security in the browser. But that will only be a temporary solution.

Comment: According this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886186/how-to-setup-access-control-allow-origin-filter-problematically-in-spring-securi), I added `.addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)` in my `WebSecurityConfig` class. Now the error becomes ` The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:54174'`. Where did that strange value come from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964297/using-request-getremoteaddr-returns-00000001

Comment: Is this a public facing application?