# WebBrowser getAdress() returns malformed ip string

Tags: java, vaadin

My app runs on a jetty server. I access it via http://localhost:8080. My problem is that `Page.getCurrent().getWebBrowser().getAddress()` returns `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` instead of something like `127.0.0.1` as stated in the javadoc:

```
/**
 * Gets the IP-address of the web browser. If the application is running
 * inside a portlet, this method will return null.
 * 
 * @return IP-address in 1.12.123.123 -format
 */
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
```

Anyone has a clue what happens here?

Comment: Possible explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964297/using-request-getremoteaddr-returns-00000001

Comment: Additionally, if you really need to, you can force to ipv4 with `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`. Refer to the [java IPv6 guide: IPv6-Related System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/#ipv6-related) for more information